# Combinatorial Probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Another exercise from Saeed Ghahramani's *Fundamentals of Probability*, paraphrased below:

> Consider a train with $n$ cars and $m > n$ passengers. Suppose passengers board cars randomly. What is the probability that at least one person is in each car?

At first I thought the problem could be approached with a stars and bars method. Let $X$ be the event of every car having at least one person aboard.

$$P(X) = \dfrac{\binom{m - 1}{n - 1}}{\binom{n + m - 1}{n}}$$

I am thinking of the cars as integers whose sum is $m$; the numerator counts the number of ways they could sum to $m$ and all be positive, and the denominator counts the number of ways they could sum to $m$ and all be non-negative.

However, Saeed gives a much different answer:
$$P(X) = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^i \binom{n}{i} (n-i)^m}{n^m}$$
WolframAlpha simplified this to
$$\dfrac{n! \mathcal{S}_m^{(n)}}{n^m}$$

where $\mathcal{S}_m^{(n)}$ is the "Stirling number of the second kind". I had not heard of these but seeing their definition as number of ways to partition a set of $n$ objects into $k$ non-empty subsets makes clear their appearance.

A few questions: 
What is wrong with my approach? What am I actually counting? Can you explain the solution given by Saeed?

Comment: when I run Saeed's formula even for small n and m I get a negative probability. Is there more to the formula? Also, I made a small change in your wording please check to see that you agree.

Comment: I approved your edit (thanks) but you should not be getting negative values if $m > n$.

Comment: Your approach is wrong: if you look at the number of persons in a given car, this number is not equidistributed. It's every person choosing his car randomly, not every car choosing randomly how many persons to accomodate.

Comment: m>n so that will not work.

Comment: @A.E Just for context, this is equivalent to the "coupon collector's problem". If you're interested in pursuing the problem further, there's a ton of literature on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, and most important, the fact that the "Stars and Bars" method is not right. We need to construct a mathematical model of the situation. We will assume that the passengers are lined up ready to board. Each passenger rolls a "fair" $n$-sided die to decide on the car she will get into. The rolls are independent.

Suppose that there are $60$ passengers, and, to keep things simple, $3$ cars. The distribution $(60,0,0)$ is far less likely than, for example, the distribution $(22,18,20)$. So treating the $\binom{n+m-1}{n}$  "Stars and Bars" ways of distributing people among cars as *equally likely* will give the wrong answer. Whenever we divide the "number of favourables" by the "total number," we have to make sure that the possibilities counted by "total number" are all equally likely.

---

Now we begin to solve the problem, using Inclusion/Exclusion. The choice of cars by the passengers is a **function** from the set of passengers to the set of cars. Under our model, each of the $n^m$ functions from the set of passengers to the set of cars is equally likely.

Now we count how many of these functions are **onto**. From the $n^m$ functions, we must subtract the functions that "miss" at least one car. There are $(n-1)^m$ functions that miss Car $1$, and the same for missing Car $2$, and so on. That gives as our first estimate of the number of "good" functions the expression
$$n^m -\binom{n-1}{1}(n-1)^m.$$
But we have subtracted too much. For we have subtracted one too many times the functions (choices) that miss both Car $1$ and Car $2$, or more generally the functions that miss Car $i$ and Car $j$. There are $(n-2)^m$ functions that miss Cars $i$ and $j$, and $\binom{n}{2}$ choices for the two cars missed. So we must *add back* $\binom{n}{2}(n-2)^m$. Our new estimate is 
$$n^m -\binom{n-1}{1}(n-1)^m+\binom{n}{2}(n-2)^m.$$

But we have added back too much, for we have added back once too many times the functions that miss Cars $i$, $j$, and $k$, where these indices are distinct. Continue!

Comment: Yes of course, now my mistake is glaringly obvious. Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome. It is a fairly common slip. Once we know how to count a certain sort of configuration, it seems natural to use the count in probability calculations.

Comment: I think this means that we should start the sum at i = 0 and not at i = 1

Comment: Sure, the formula for $P(X)$ attributed by OP to the book is wrong. But the *spirit* is right.

Comment: One way I have found to avoid this sort of confusion is to always have a story in time order for how the objects are chosen. For the "stars and bars" the stars and bars can be seen as a description of how to construct the configuration. The stars tell you to let another person onto this car, the bar tells you to close the door on this car and move to the next one. The only way randomness can get into this story is in the choice of whether to let someone on or switch cars. Since there have to be a certain number of people, it is not at all clear how the probability will work at each choice!